# Why are my formulas not calculated in some columns in libreoffice calc

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc

I have a libreoffice calc sheet that calculates simple formulas (`=2+2`) in some cells but not in others. It used to fetch data using `=WEBSERVICE`, but I removed everything but simple calculations while trying to find a problem source and it still behaves that way, so I assume it some kind of formatting option.

How do I make it calculate all cells?
Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]
Edit: added screenshots to clarify that B16 and C16 contain the same `=2+2` formula
[image: Screenshot]
[image: Working formula in B16]
[image: Non-working formula in C16]

Comment: Hello and welcome to superuser! Before posting, be sure to search the web — in this case, you can simply copy and paste your title to search. If nothing helps, then describe what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Select the cell and take a screen capture of the bar that shows the underlying formula. Does it say `'=2+2` perhaps, which is simply a string?

The way to show a formula is *View > Show Formula*.

This question has also been answered at:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59665808/libreoffice-calc-shows-formulas-in-the-cell-instead-of-results
- https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/i-cannot-get-a-formula-to-work-in-libreoffice-calc/20127

Comment: It's `=2+2` without '. It looks the same in B16 and C16. I added screenshot to clarify.

Comment: The provided links does not solve the issue, enabling formula view via edit->show formula. Makes both C16 and B16 show `=2+2` without any additional characters.